# adding child nodes to a treeview control in wpf,c#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

i have implemented a treeview control on a buttonclick event like this:

```
namespace TaxonomyTreeview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<TaxonomyData> _TaxonomyCollection = new ObservableCollection<TaxonomyData>();

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TaxonomyData> TaxonomyCollection
        { get { return _TaxonomyCollection; } }

        private void SelectedTaxonomyChanged(object sender,
                         RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
        {
            TaxonomyData taxo = taxonomytree.SelectedItem as TaxonomyData;
            if (taxo != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + taxo.Tid);
            }
        }

        public class TaxonomyData
        {
            private string _name;
            private string _tid;

            public string Tid
            {
                get { return _tid; }
                set { _tid = value; }
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
                set { _name = value; }
            }

            public TaxonomyData(string name, string tid)
            {
                Name = name;
                Tid = tid;
            }
        }

        private void populate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            taxonomytree.Items.Clear();
            TaxonomyCollection.Add(new TaxonomyData("Taxonomy1", "1"));

            taxonomytree.Items.Add(TaxonomyCollection[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml code is :

```
<Window x:Class="TaxonomyTreeview.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="435" Width="458" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>

    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="20,9,0,0" Name="startvid" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="165,9,151,0" Name="endvid" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Height="23.78" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8.22,11,0" Name="populate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Click="populate_Click">Populate</Button>
    <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,53,0,144" Width="120"  Name="taxonomytree"  ItemsSource="{Binding Window1.TaxonomyCollection}" 
      SelectedItemChanged="SelectedTaxonomyChanged">
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

As i want to display, the structure in a hierarchy, i want to know what is the best method to add a child node to this

Please help

**UPDATE:**
But that doesn't solve the problem

How would I assign a child object to "Taxonomy1","Tid=1"

My question was to display the data in a hierarchical data format in the treeview in real time at runtime?

This is a solution but the original question was to display it in a hierarchy like this:

Vocabulary 1

|

| - Taxonomy1, Tid1

| - Taxonomy2, Tid2

Vocabulary 2

|

| - Taxonomy 1, Tid3

| - Taxonomy 2, Tid4

Comment: Do you wish to add a child node to a TaxonomyData element in the TaxonomyCollection?

Comment: yes i do

more specific
the populate_Click button click event populates a treeview with element values "Taxonomy1", "1"
i want to add a child element to this in the treeview

Answer (score 4):

Your data structure doesn't support parent/child relationships, so your UI's not going to be able to either.

The first place to start is by adding a `Children` property of type `ObservableCollection<TaxonomyData>` to your `TaxonomyData` class.

To display these items, you need to use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.  This is just like a normal `DataTemplate` except that it's got an `ItemsSource` property that tells it where to get the item's child objects.  The template itself produces the header of the `TreeViewItem` that it generates, and the `ItemsSource` tells it where to get the child items:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TaxonomyData}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

To add new items, you make your `Click` event handler look something like this:

```
if (taxonomytree.SelectedItem == null)
{
   TaxonomyCollection.Add(new TaxonomyData("foo", "bar");
}
else
{
   TaxonomyData td = (TaxonomyData) taxonomytree.SelectedItem;
   td.Children.Add(new TaxonomyData("foo", "bar"));
}
```

That will add a child the currently-selected item, and if there is no currently-selected item, it will add it to the top-level collection.

In no event should your code touch the `Items` property of the `TreeView`, as your present code does.  The `TreeView` is populated by data binding.  Manage the `TaxonomyCollection` collection, and data binding will take care of the `TreeView`s items for you.

Comment: or can u tell me how to modify my data str. to support parent-child relationship please
and then if necessary how to change the code accordingly

Comment: What part of my answer don't you understand?  I'm sure it's not totally clear.  What are you having trouble with?